# Rescale rectangle (Top, Left, Bottom, right)

Tags: c#, rectangles, bounding-box, rescale

Original question: [Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994690/how-can-i-transform-xy-coordinates-and-height-width-on-a-scaled-image-to-an-orig**strong%20text**)

I have an image *I1* of size `height x width = (1500,500)` resized to `(500,300)`.

*I1* contains bounding boxes characterized by their coordinates `(Top, Left, Bottom, Right)`.

---

How can rescale the coordinates of the bounding boxes when The size of *I1* is changed? are these formulas correct?

```
   double newTop = Math.Ceiling((top) * (double)pictureBox1.Height / (double)image1.Height);
   double newLeft = Math.Ceiling((left) * (double)pictureBox1.Width / (double)image1.Width);
   double newBottom = Math.Ceiling((bottom + 1) * (double)pictureBox1.Height / (double)image1.Height) - 1;
   double newRight = Math.Ceiling((right + 1) * (double)pictureBox1.Width / (double)image1.Width) - 1;
```

---

Comment: Seems ok from a brief look without actually trying it.

Comment: Are you sure you should be doing integer divisons? Seems to me you are going to run into some massive errors unless I'm completely misunderstanding your code.

Comment: @InBetween you are right. Maybe because of the integers i am not being able to rescale the bounding box correctly. I'll try it now.

Shoud I take the uppder or lower bounds? for the division

Comment: The code looks like C#, so why have you added the C++ tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:

Sizes scale by the factor (new-size)/(old-size).

Coordinates are a bit more complex:

```
x2 = left2 + (x1 - left1) * width2 / width1
y2 = top2 + (y1 - top1) * height2 / height1
```

where `left` and `width`, etc describe the location of the entire image.  `x` and `y` describe the feature being transformed.  In your case, corners of the bounding boxes are features.

If `left1`, `left2`, `top1`, `top2` are all zero, you will get expressions similar to yours.