# Translating a Rectangle from Larger Image to Smaller One

Tags: c#, .net, math, geometry, system.drawing

I need to do lengthy processing on a large image file.So before processing i resize it.At the end of the processing coordinates of a rectangle within the resized image is returned.How can i translate this rectangle/coordinates of the rectangle to a rectangle in the non resized full size image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I transform XY coordinates and height/width on a scaled image to an original sized image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994690/how-can-i-transform-xy-coordinates-and-height-width-on-a-scaled-image-to-an-orig)

Answer (score 0):

Resizing is linear transformation, so new coordinate of some point is calculated as

```
 X_New = Ax * X_Old + Bx
```

To get it back, just use reverse transform

```
 X_Old = (X_New - Bx) / Ax
```

Comment: They are defined by your resizing

Comment: For example i have to translate a point (x,y) within an resized image(smaller size) to the larger image .. i do the following `xt=(x-largeimagewidth)/smallimagewidth` ? i'm i right? could you add some more explanation.

Comment: If you extend image without shifting (no B coefficient)  `x_large = x_small * largeimagewidth / smallimagewidth` and vice versa `x_small = x_large * smallimagewidth / largeimagewidth`